# Need to do a SQL join between two tables and need to compare multiple different rows

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have done SQL joins for years, but this one has me stumped for some reason. I have two tables like so:

**`task`**:

```
 taskid description created_date target_date
      1 test        01-01-2019   2/1/2019
      2 test        01-01-2019   2/1/2019
      3 test        01-01-2019   2/1/2019
      4 test        01-01-2019   2/1/2019
```

**`task_tag`**:

```
 taskid tagid created date
 1      1     1/1/2019
 1      2     1/1/2019
 1      3     1/1/2019
 1      4     1/1/2019
 2      1     1/1/2019
 2      2     1/1/2019
 2      3     1/1/2019
 2      4     1/1/2019
```

With the `taskid` I am trying to query task_tag table for taskid's that contain more than 1 specific `tagid`.

For example the query could look something like this:

```
SELECT tsk.task_id, tsk.description, tsk.created_date, tsk.target_date
 FROM task_tags tag
 JOIN task tsk ON tsk.task_id = tag.task_id
 WHERE tag.tag_id = 1 AND tag.tag_id = 2 AND tag.tag_id = 3
```

I am hoping for an output similar to the task table however filtered by `taskid`'s that have `tag.tag_id`'s that matches the where clause. Make sense?

Comment: Please include desired output that demonstrates 'contain more than 1 specific `tagid`'. `tag.tag_id = 1 AND tag.tag_id = 2 AND tag.tag_id = 3` can never be try as the `tag.tag_id` will never contain these 3 values at the same time. Do you just want to `GROUP BY taskid` and list those with a `COUNT(*) > 1` per group?

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```
    SELECT tsk.task_id
        , tsk.description
        , tsk.created_date
        , tsk.target_date
        , count(tag.tag_id) as tagCount FROM task tsk  JOIN   task_tags tag  ON tag.task_id = tsk.task_id 
And tag.tag_id in (1, 2, 3)
Group by tsk.task_id
        , tsk.description
        , tsk.created_date
        , tsk.target_date Having count(tag.tag_id) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks, I got this one to work, however with one caveat. The counter in the having clause is a little challenging for me. I need each task to have a minimum of 3 tags, which works fine. The issue I have is when someone enters another tag by mistake that is one I am comparing with. It finds 3 matches and thus returns it as a result it shouldnt. For example if i have a tag 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. Say I want a task to have at least 1, 2 and. But if I filter by having > 2 and it finds 4 or 5 in the comparison it will return true even though it might be missing 1, 2  or 3. It only needs 3 matches.